# Forcing Acrobat Reader font

Tags: fonts, adobe-acrobat

I have a netbook with Linpus Linux and I'm trying to open automatically generated documents with Acrobat Reader that use Verdana but without having it embedded inside the PDF file.

Linpus doesn't come natively with any Verdana font so I had to install them inside `/usr/share/fonts/`by doing `mkfontdir`and `fc-cache`to force a recache of the fonts. Then I've been able to select it inside other programs (eg. OpenOffice) but I'm still unable to open these PDFs. It seems that Acrobat is unable to find the font anyway.

Since I have no control on how these PDFs are generated, is there a way to force Acrobat to use a specific font is the one it needs is unfound? Or maybe Acrobat needs a different kind of font configuration on Linux?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't even *open* the PDFs? Or they just display the wrong font when you do? Is there a reason you can't use evince or okular instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have acrobat reader pro (windows) v8, but a quick google search indicates that reader standard may also include the "touch-up text" tool. In my install, it is in the tools menu under "advanced". The tool allows for selecting text, choosing "properties" and picking a new typeface. On the one doc I tried, each section of text was a separate layout box, and I was unable to select all and change it globally. It may be possible, but I did not dig further.

---

I also found this link:

http://www.linux-archive.org/debian-user/322514-font-substitution-acroread.html

Which may provide some useful information. The person located several locations that acroread was checking for fonts. Plus, if you can find out what the font name is that acrobat is looking for, you can create an alias.

```
> I managed that by creating
> ~/.fonts.conf file with the following
> content.
> 
> *** <fontconfig> <alias binding="same">
> <family>Helvetica</family> <prefer>
> <family>Arial</family> </prefer>
> </alias> </fontconfig>
> ***
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "Acrobat Reader Pro". I assume you mean Acrobat Pro. But no, Adobe Reader does not include the touch-up text feature. The fontconfig trick would help, how? Mapping Verdana to Verdana? In my experience, Adobe Reader doesn't respect fontconfig settings in .fonts anyway.

Comment: The fontconfig trick *might* work if the name of the font varies and software thinks it is a different font. If he can look at the properties of the doc and determine the font name it wants, he can alias it. And "yes" I meant acrobat pro, the word "reader" was left behind during composition of the reply. My experience with adobe products in windows is the same. I always have to create a shortcut to the windows fonts folder in the adobe common folder ({PROGRAM FILES}\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts). That is why I mentioned the "several locations acroread was checking"